# How to get the original variable name of variable passed to a function

Tags: python, function, variables

Is it possible to get the original variable name of a variable passed to a function? E.g.

```
foobar = "foo"

def func(var):
    print var.origname
```

So that:

```
func(foobar)
```

Returns:

`foobar`

I was trying to make a function like:

```
def log(soup):
    f = open(varname+'.html', 'w')
    print >>f, soup.prettify()
    f.close()
```

and have the function generate the filename from the name of the variable passed to it.

I suppose if it's not possible I'll just have to pass the variable and the variable's name as a string each time.

Comment: No. Perhaps if you describe what you are trying achieve on a higher level, we can give you some pointers or alternative solutions?

Comment: I'm mainly wondering why you would want it? 

Afaik it's not possible, never heard of anybody wanting to do it before though.

Comment: Related: [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18425225/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea clear duplicate IMO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't. It's evaluated before being passed to the function. All you can do is pass it as a string.

Comment: Is there then maybe a way to take a variable and save its name as a string?

Comment: You could access the `locals()` and `globals()` dictionaries and look for variables that match the value, but that's really inelegant. Better to simply pass it manually: `log('myvar', myvar)`.

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong, and the answer below from @Aeon is correct.

Comment: "Is there then maybe a way to take a variable and save its name as a string?" Think of it the other way around: if you have multiple things that you want to pass to the function, why are they separately named variables in the first place? Instead, collect related pieces of information that need an identifying "key", into *the data structure designed for that exact purpose*: a `dict`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/

Answer (score 113):

**EDIT:** To make it clear, I don't recommend using this AT ALL, it will break, it's a mess, it won't help you in any way, but it's doable for entertainment/education purposes.

You can hack around with the `inspect` module, I don't recommend that, but you can do it...

```
import inspect

def foo(a, f, b):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    frame = inspect.getouterframes(frame)[1]
    string = inspect.getframeinfo(frame[0]).code_context[0].strip()
    args = string[string.find('(') + 1:-1].split(',')
    
    names = []
    for i in args:
        if i.find('=') != -1:
            names.append(i.split('=')[1].strip())
        
        else:
            names.append(i)
    
    print names

def main():
    e = 1
    c = 2
    foo(e, 1000, b = c)

main()
```

Output:

```
['e', '1000', 'c']
```

Comment: +1: One of the hackiest pieces of code I've seen in a long time.

Comment: Being the hackiest code in a long time deserves a +1? I'd've flipped the sign there.

Comment: As I said, I don't recommend using that, nor would I ever use such a hack. Using inspect is IMO always a sign that something is going horrible, horrible wrong. I just wanted to show that it's possible... but as we all know, you shouldn't do something JUST because it's possible.

Comment: @Devin: Using such code in a real application would deserve a -1. Writing it to show that something unusual can be achieved through an ingenious abuse of reflection is impressive, and certainly deserves a +1.

Comment: I'd like code like `d = pack(a,b,c)` that was equivalent to `d = dict(); d['a'] = a; d['b'] = b; d['c'] = c` - because it's a construct I use all the time and I'm lazy...

Comment: Can you expound upon the circumstances that cause it to break? If you know that the methods you pass in won't be confused with methods/variables with the same name, does it still break? I'm just thinking it would be a good idea to clarify how it's a bad idea.

Comment: `foo(e, 1000, lambda x: x == 1)`

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx : If you call `foo(...)` multiple times on the same line, it will be unable to tell wich occurence was called at that time. Also, if you call is split on multiple lines, you wont have it all.

Comment: using *argv in arguments instead of a,f,b can make it accept varialbe number of parameters

Comment: +1 although I disagree with "You can hack around with the inspect module, I don't recommend that". People should hack around with it as much as possible to get a better understanding of python.

Comment: Bonus: how do you call `foo()` from within another function `bar()` and have it return the name of the variables originally fed to `bar()`?

Answer (score 26):

To add to [Michael Mrozek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10361425), you can extract the exact parameters versus the full code by:

```
import re
import traceback

def func(var):
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    filename, lineno, function_name, code = stack[-2]
    vars_name = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\).*$').search(code).groups()[0]
    print vars_name
    return

foobar = "foo"

func(foobar)

# PRINTS: foobar
```

Comment: If you want to make this into a function, just have stack[-3] instead of stack[-2].

Answer (score 15):

Looks like Ivo beat me to `inspect`, but here's another implementation:

```
import inspect

def varName(var):
    lcls = inspect.stack()[2][0].f_locals
    for name in lcls:
        if id(var) == id(lcls[name]):
            return name
    return None

def foo(x=None):
    lcl='not me'
    return varName(x)

def bar():
    lcl = 'hi'
    return foo(lcl)

bar()
# 'lcl'
```

Of course, it can be fooled:

```
def baz():
    lcl = 'hi'
    x='hi'
    return foo(lcl)

baz()
# 'x'
```

Moral: don't do it.

Comment: This is a really smart solution, but it won't catch things like `f(obj.attr)`.

Answer (score 12):

Another way you can try if you know what the calling code will look like is to use [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html):

```
def func(var):
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    filename, lineno, function_name, code = stack[-2]
```

`code` will contain the line of code that was used to call `func` (in your example, it would be the string `func(foobar)`). You can parse that to pull out the argument

Answer (score 8):

@Ivo Wetzel's answer works in the case of function call are made in one line, like

```
e = 1 + 7
c = 3
foo(e, 100, b=c)
```

In case that function call is not in one line, like:

```
e = 1 + 7
c = 3
foo(e,
    1000,
    b = c)
```

below code works:

```
import inspect, ast

def foo(a, f, b):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    frame = inspect.getouterframes(frame)[1]
    string = inspect.findsource(frame[0])[0]

    nodes = ast.parse(''.join(string))

    i_expr = -1
    for (i, node) in enumerate(nodes.body):
        if hasattr(node, 'value') and isinstance(node.value, ast.Call)
            and hasattr(node.value.func, 'id') and node.value.func.id == 'foo'  # Here goes name of the function:
            i_expr = i
            break

    i_expr_next = min(i_expr + 1, len(nodes.body)-1)  
    lineno_start = nodes.body[i_expr].lineno
    lineno_end = nodes.body[i_expr_next].lineno if i_expr_next != i_expr else len(string)

    str_func_call = ''.join([i.strip() for i in string[lineno_start - 1: lineno_end]])
    params = str_func_call[str_func_call.find('(') + 1:-1].split(',')

    print(params)
```

You will get:

```
[u'e', u'1000', u'b = c']
```

But still, this might break.

Answer (score 4):

For posterity, here's some code I wrote for this task, in general I think there is a missing module in Python to give everyone nice and robust inspection of the caller environment. Similar to what rlang eval framework provides for R.

```
import re, inspect, ast

#Convoluted frame stack walk and source scrape to get what the calling statement to a function looked like.
#Specifically return the name of the variable passed as parameter found at position pos in the parameter list.
def _caller_param_name(pos):
    #The parameter name to return
    param = None
    #Get the frame object for this function call
    thisframe = inspect.currentframe()
    try:
        #Get the parent calling frames details
        frames = inspect.getouterframes(thisframe)
        #Function this function was just called from that we wish to find the calling parameter name for
        function = frames[1][3]
        #Get all the details of where the calling statement was
        frame,filename,line_number,function_name,source,source_index = frames[2]
        #Read in the source file in the parent calling frame upto where the call was made
        with open(filename) as source_file:
            head=[source_file.next() for x in xrange(line_number)]
        source_file.close()

        #Build all lines of the calling statement, this deals with when a function is called with parameters listed on each line
        lines = []
        #Compile a regex for matching the start of the function being called
        regex = re.compile(r'\.?\s*%s\s*\(' % (function))
        #Work backwards from the parent calling frame line number until we see the start of the calling statement (usually the same line!!!)
        for line in reversed(head):
            lines.append(line.strip())
            if re.search(regex, line):
                break
        #Put the lines we have groked back into sourcefile order rather than reverse order
        lines.reverse()
        #Join all the lines that were part of the calling statement
        call = "".join(lines)
        #Grab the parameter list from the calling statement for the function we were called from
        match = re.search('\.?\s*%s\s*\((.*)\)' % (function), call)
        paramlist = match.group(1)
        #If the function was called with no parameters raise an exception
        if paramlist == "":
            raise LookupError("Function called with no parameters.")
        #Use the Python abstract syntax tree parser to create a parsed form of the function parameter list 'Name' nodes are variable names
        parameter = ast.parse(paramlist).body[0].value
        #If there were multiple parameters get the positional requested
        if type(parameter).__name__ == 'Tuple':
            #If we asked for a parameter outside of what was passed complain
            if pos >= len(parameter.elts):
                raise LookupError("The function call did not have a parameter at postion %s" % pos)
            parameter = parameter.elts[pos]
        #If there was only a single parameter and another was requested raise an exception
        elif pos != 0:
            raise LookupError("There was only a single calling parameter found. Parameter indices start at 0.")
        #If the parameter was the name of a variable we can use it otherwise pass back None
        if type(parameter).__name__ == 'Name':
            param = parameter.id
    finally:
        #Remove the frame reference to prevent cyclic references screwing the garbage collector
        del thisframe
    #Return the parameter name we found
    return param
```

Comment: for 'posterity'.
also opening the source file in the middle of a function call is dubious at best.

Comment: @vwvan yup so dubious there is a Python built in for it you should use instead of rolling your own https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource If security is something you care about never do anything fun. I would also like to bet some bitcoins that the core implementation does absolutely nothing important to ensure inspecting the source is what is running in RAM and does in fact hit disk. I want to be wrong on that one, I might go spelunking and report back.

Answer (score 4):

You can use python-varname package

```
from varname import nameof

s = 'Hey!'

print (nameof(s))
```

Output:

```
s
```

Package below:

https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname

Comment: Surprisingly it has worked for me when apply a function to columns of a dataframe. However it returns both the argument name as is and the actual name.

Comment: You should actually use `argname()`

Answer (score 3):

If you want a Key Value Pair relationship, maybe using a Dictionary would be better?

...or if you're trying to create some auto-documentation from your code, perhaps something like Doxygen (http://www.doxygen.nl/) could do the job for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the caller params as in [@Matt Oates answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58131854/3126337) answer without using the source file (ie from Jupyter Notebook), this code (combined from [@Aeon answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38434232/3126337)) will do the trick (at least in some simple cases):

```py
def get_caller_params():
    # get the frame object for this function call
    thisframe = inspect.currentframe()

    # get the parent calling frames details
    frames = inspect.getouterframes(thisframe)

    # frame 0 is the frame of this function
    # frame 1 is the frame of the caller function (the one we want to inspect)
    # frame 2 is the frame of the code that calls the caller
    caller_function_name = frames[1][3]
    code_that_calls_caller = inspect.findsource(frames[2][0])[0]

    # parse code to get nodes of abstract syntact tree of the call
    nodes = ast.parse(''.join(code_that_calls_caller))

    # find the node that calls the function
    i_expr = -1
    for (i, node) in enumerate(nodes.body):
        if _node_is_our_function_call(node, caller_function_name):
            i_expr = i
            break

    # line with the call start
    idx_start = nodes.body[i_expr].lineno - 1

    # line with the end of the call
    if i_expr < len(nodes.body) - 1:
        # next expression marks the end of the call
        idx_end = nodes.body[i_expr + 1].lineno - 1
    else:
        # end of the source marks the end of the call
        idx_end = len(code_that_calls_caller)

    call_lines = code_that_calls_caller[idx_start:idx_end]
    str_func_call = ''.join([line.strip() for line in call_lines])
    str_call_params = str_func_call[str_func_call.find('(') + 1:-1]
    params = [p.strip() for p in str_call_params.split(',')]

    return params


def _node_is_our_function_call(node, our_function_name):
    node_is_call = hasattr(node, 'value') and isinstance(node.value, ast.Call)
    if not node_is_call:
        return False

    function_name_correct = hasattr(node.value.func, 'id') and node.value.func.id == our_function_name
    return function_name_correct
```

You can then run it as this:

```py
def test(*par_values):
    par_names = get_caller_params()
    for name, val in zip(par_names, par_values):
        print(name, val)


a = 1
b = 2
string = 'text'
test(a, b,
  string
)
```

to get the desired output:

```
a 1
b 2
string text
```

Comment: can this be improves so that the `par_name` is None if called with a constant, i.e. `test("x", 1000)` should print `None x` then `None 1000` ?

Answer (score 2):

I wondered how [IceCream](https://github.com/gruns/icecream) solves this problem. So I looked into [the source code](https://github.com/gruns/icecream/blob/master/icecream/icecream.py) and came up with the following (slightly simplified) solution. It might not be 100% bullet-proof (e.g. I dropped `get_text_with_indentation` and I assume exactly one function argument), but it works well for different test cases. It does not need to parse source code itself, so it should be more robust and simpler than previous solutions.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import inspect
from executing import Source
    
def func(var):
    callFrame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    callNode = Source.executing(callFrame).node
    source = Source.for_frame(callFrame)
    expression = source.asttokens().get_text(callNode.args[0])
    print(expression, '=', var)
    
i = 1
f = 2.0
dct = {'key': 'value'}
obj = type('', (), {'value': 42})
    
func(i)
func(f)
func(s)
func(dct['key'])
func(obj.value)
```

Output:

```py
i = 1
f = 2.0
s = string
dct['key'] = value
obj.value = 42
```

---

Update: If you want to move the "magic" into a separate function, you simply have to go one frame further back with an additional `f_back`.

```py
def get_name_of_argument():
    callFrame = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back
    callNode = Source.executing(callFrame).node
    source = Source.for_frame(callFrame)
    return source.asttokens().get_text(callNode.args[0])

def func(var):
    print(get_name_of_argument(), '=', var)
```

Comment: How would  you use get_name_of_argument() as a method inside a class?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have multiple variables with the same content, instead of passing the variable (content), it might be safer (and will be simpler) to pass it's name in a string and get the variable content from the locals dictionary in the callers stack frame. :

```
def displayvar(name):
    import sys
    return name+" = "+repr(sys._getframe(1).f_locals[name])
```

Answer (score 0):

If it just so happens that the variable is a callable (function), it will have a `__name__` property.

E.g. a wrapper to log the execution time of a function:

```py
def time_it(func, *args, **kwargs):
    start = perf_counter()
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    duration = perf_counter() - start

    print(f'{func.__name__} ran in {duration * 1000}ms')

    return result
```

Comment: It's good approach, but not available for integers: 'int' object has no attribute '__name__'