# How get names of passed parameters inside a function

Tags: python, ipython

Is there a simple way to get the names of the parameters passed to a Python function, from inside the function?

I'm building an interactive image processing tool that works at the Python command line.

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
beta = alpha * 2;  # double all pixel values in numpy array  
save(beta)         # save image beta in filename "beta.jpg"
```

The alternative is to make the user explicitly type the filename, which is extra typing I'd like to avoid:

```
beta = alpha * 2;  # double all pixel values in numpy array  
save(beta, "beta") # save image beta in filename "beta.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. And thanks for not saying "there's no reason why anyone should want to do that".

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you cannot.

[How to get the original variable name of variable passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749796/how-to-get-the-original-variable-name-of-variable-passed-to-a-function)

However, you COULD do something like this

```
def save(**kwargs):
    for item in kwargs:
        print item #This is the name of the variable you passed in
        print kwargs[item] #This is the value of the variable you passed in.
save(test='toast')
```

Although, it is probably better practice to do this as such

```
def save(name,value):
    print name
    print value

save("test","toast")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the "name" of a parameter, but you could do something like this to pass the name and the value in a dictionary:

```
save({"beta": alpha*2})
```

Now, inside the `save()` function:

```
def save(param):
    # assuming Python 2.x
    name  = param.keys()[0]
    # assuming Python 3.x
    name  = next(param.keys())
    value = param[name]
```

Notice that in general, in a programming language you're not interested in the *name* of a parameter, that's irrelevant - what matters is its *value*.

Comment: In 3.x you could just do list(param.keys()).

Comment: @ollien yep, but that won't return the first (and only) key in the dict. But surely, a solution that works for 2.x and 3.x would be: `list(param.keys())[0]`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez `next(iter(param))` will work identically on both

Comment: That might be useful if I were writing a program, but the idea is that the user (non-programmer, but math aware) is at the command line doing math on images. Asking them to deal with dictionary syntax is too much, I think.

Comment: @nerdfever.com Then pass two parameters to the function, and forget about trying to obtain the parameter's name (anyway that's a bad idea). Besides, in Python we use dictionaries all the time, the syntax will be familiar to anyone with a minimum of experience with the language.