# Check if substring present in variable name - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that takes a given variable as an argument.
This variable is a numpy array. Example in pseudo-code:

```
def foo(var):
   if 'test' in the name of var:
      do something

return
```

I have tried different options, like

```
if 'test' in var:
```

or

```
if var == 'test_complete_name_of_var'
```

But these just check the values of the array, and not the variable name.
I was hoping there could be some sort of trick such as:

```
if 'test' in var.name()
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: You can't easily do that. Why not change the function signature to `def foo(var, test=False):`?

Comment: Usually if you want to do something like that you can create a dictionary and store the variable under a name. This way you can also check for it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749796/how-to-get-the-original-variable-name-of-variable-passed-to-a-function

Comment: might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Comment: I think you're missing the way that names work in Python work on many levels. In the function, your name is hard-coded to `var`. You don't need a function to tell you that. Outside the function, many names can refer to the same object. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: I think the solution with the dictionary could work for the current problem.
The reason to do it: the variables that belong to a certain group of variables should be treated a bit different within the same function that the variables that belong to another group. I thought this could be a very simple way to do it, as the variable names in the code are unique.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't want the function to tell me the name of the variable. I want the function to act slightly different according to a substring present in the variable name. I think it's different, or otherwise, I am not understanding your point.

Comment: @jotNewie. You named argument `var`. It is hard coded. So you can do `if 'test' in 'var':`. If that is not what you are looking for, please clarify the question. Either I don't understand what you are trying to do, or you do not understand how names work in python...

Comment: @Andreas could you put your answer as a proper answer, so that I can mark it as the solution? Thanks!

Comment: @joNewie yes, thank you for accepting it .!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you want to do something like that you can create a dictionary and store the variable under a name. This way you can also check for it.

Example:

```
dict_variables = {}
dict_variables["var_1"] = ["a", "b", "test"]

def foo(var_name):
    var_value = dict_variables.get(var_name)
    if 'var_' in var_name:
       print(var_value)
       
foo("var_1")
#out: ['a', 'b', 'test']
```

Usefull e.g. for path and dataframe variables.

Answer (score 0):

First, install the varname library

```
pip install python-varname
```

then use it as the following example:

```
from varname import nameof

def foo(var):
    if 'test' in nameof(var):
      ###do something
```

Comment: That sounds like massive overkill. The name is literally hard-coded to `var`. That's just how the language works

Comment: And how would you check if the name contains a certain string?

Comment: `if 'test' in 'var':`

Comment: While I think that the library is neat, I have no idea why it is even remotely useful. I can't think of any use-case where knowing the name something is being assigned to leads to robust code.