# How do I get the raw value of a variable?

Tags: python-3.x

It's a little hard to explain what I want to do because I don't know much python programming terminology.

Basically I want to be able to do something like this this:

```py
var = list("blah blah")
print(str(var))
```

And get this:

```
Output:

list("blah blah")
```

And not this:

```
Output:

['b', 'l', 'a', 'h', ' ', 'b', 'l', 'a', 'h']
```

Or do something like this:

```py
a = str(4+(6*3)) + " Test"
print(str(a))
```

And get this:

```py
Output:

str(4+(6*3)) + " Test"
```

And not this:

```py
Output:

22 Test
```

Comment: There is probably a simple answer to this question I am just too much of a rookie to find out what it is

Comment: It  depends on what context you want to use this in. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427453/3000206) may work in some cases if the code is wrapped in a function. Generally though, you'd need a macro that views the code before it's evaluated.

Comment: It seems like you're basically in https://stackoverflow.com/q/2749796/3001761 territory. Python evaluates the expression and stores the *result* in `var`. What's the *context* - what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah like trying to get the original variable name, but instead trying to get the original variable value.

Comment: Do you know at which line in the file the variable is being assigned?

Comment: Why not store everything in a string and evaluate it later, assuming you need it evaluated at all?

Comment: I guess I could store it in a string but it would be preferable to just get the raw value of something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```py
import re # 0
# 1
l = list('list') # 2

filecontent = open(__file__, "r").read()

varline = re.sub('\s*#.*$', '', re.split('\s*=\s*', filecontent.split('\n')[2])[1])
print(varline)
```

Explanation:

`import re # Line 0` - import the regex module

`l = list('list') # Line 2` - set the variable `l`

`filecontent = open(__file__, "r").read()` - read the current file's content

`varline = re.sub('\s*#.*$', '', re.split('\s*=\s*', filecontent.split('\n')[2])[1])` - Get the 3rd line's content (where the variable is being declared) and filter it to only include the variable's content, and not even comments

`print(varline)` - print the content

Comment: I guess this works, I wish there was some library that made this less complex or something but this will have to do. Thank you.