# Python - Get text of arguments passed to a function and use it to assign global variables

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, global-variables

I've created a function that takes datframe as an argument. I can get different results from the function by changing the name of the dataframe. I want to get the argument that specifies the df to the function to use as text.

```
def my_func(df, prop=True):
    fd = df.C1.value_counts(normalize=prop).reset_index()
    fd.columns = ['feature','proportion']
    return fd
# Note: I pass this function within another function that builds a graph using fd

import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['A','A','B','D']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['C','C','B','D']})

my_func(df2)
#   feature  proportion
# 0       C        0.50
# 1       D        0.25
# 2       B        0.25
```

**Desired Functionality**
I want to be able to save fd for the dataframes with the names fd_df1 and fd_df2 right within the function my_func, which I can then call globally.
So, I figured that if there was a way to get the text of the arguments passed to a function, then I can use that to create global variables from withn my_func.
Like so:

```
def my_func(df, prop=True):
    fd = df.C1.value_counts(normalize=prop).reset_index()
    fd.columns = ['feature','count','proportion']
    df_name = get_text_of_arg()[0]       # here I want the code that gets 
                                         # 'df1' or 'df2', whatever df is used in function
    global df_name_fd          # create unique name as global variable
    df_name_fd = fd            # save fd with unique name
    return fd
```

```
my_func(df2)     # returs fd for df1 and saves it with unique name df1_fd
#   feature  proportion
# 0       C        0.50
# 1       D        0.25
# 2       B        0.25
```

```
# Calling the fd for df1
df2_fd
#   feature  proportion
# 0       C        0.50
# 1       D        0.25
# 2       B        0.25
```

Comment: this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749796/how-to-get-the-original-variable-name-of-variable-passed-to-a-function) but not recommended in any way.

Comment: I've read similar disclaimers elsewhere as well. Why is it not advisable?

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this answer by saying this should not be done. If you want to have access to the results, then maintain a collection of results. First the solution you asked for but should not use (credits to [Ivo Wetzel here for the lookup on the attribute names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749796/how-to-get-the-original-variable-name-of-variable-passed-to-a-function)):

```
import inspect
import functools
import pandas as pd


def return_df_to_globals(prefix):
    def _return_df_to_globals(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapped(df, *args, **kwargs):
            frame = inspect.currentframe()
            frame = inspect.getouterframes(frame)[1]
            string = inspect.getframeinfo(frame[0]).code_context[0].strip()
            assignments = string[string.find('(') + 1:-1].split(',')
            df_input_name = next(v for k, v in map(lambda a: a.split("="), assignments) if k.strip() == "df")
            ret = f(df, *args, **kwargs)
            globals()["_".join([prefix, df_input_name])] = ret
            return ret
        return wrapped
    return _return_df_to_globals

@return_df_to_globals(prefix="f")
def my_func(df, prop=True):
    fd = df.value_counts(normalize=prop).reset_index()
    fd.columns = ['feature','count','proportion']
    return fd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['A','A','B'], 'C2':[10,20,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['C','C','B'], 'C2':[100,200,300]})
my_func(prop=True, df=df1)
f_df1  # exists, with return value of the call.
```

On your question regarding why this is not advisible:

- To get to the argument names as needed, you need to inspect frame information from the interpreter stack. It is not intended for such uses and I am sure there will be corner-cases that break above example (maybe somebody else can elaborate).
- Separating commands and queries (see [command query separation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html)) is generally considered good style and avoids unwanted misconceptions about the system state. Your function both has side-effects (it adds to the global namespace) and returns the results of a query. Fowler's article mentions also valid exceptions to the principle - a cache might also be another good one.
- Along the lines of the last point: You could very easily override a name in the global namespace.

You have already made one improvement (providing the name explicitly). To not pollute or otherwise endanger the global namespace, here is a suggestion:

```
import inspect
import functools

def collec_result(f):
    # check that function does not use parameter names used by cache
    if {"collect_in", "collect_name"}.intersection(inspect.signature(f).parameters.keys()):
        raise ValueError("Error: function signature contains parameters collect_in or collect_name.")
        
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def fun(*args, **kwargs):
        collect_in = kwargs.pop("collect_in", None)
        collect_name = kwargs.pop("collect_name", None)
        ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        if collect_in is not None and collect_name is not None:
            collect_in[collect_name] = ret
        return ret
    return fun
```

You can then decorate your functions with `collec_result` and use `collect_in` with a dictionary (modifications to `SimpleNamespace` or similar also possible) and `collect_name` using the naming strategy you employed also in your solution whenever you wish to write the result also to a dictionary:

```
results = {}

@collect_result
def foo(a, b):
    return a+b

foo(1, 2, 
    collect_in=results,
    collect_name="123")

results["123"]  # 3
```

Of course, still better would be to just:

```
ret = foo(1, 2)
results["my_result"] = ret
```

Which then means that in whatever local scope (rendering all work above for naught) we could just:

```
my_result = foo(1, 2)
# or as in your case instead of func(df2, 'df2')
df2 = func(df2)
```

Then command-query-separation is adhered to. You don't need to silently modify the global namespace and are overall far more fault-resilient than otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My intent was a) to find some one-liner that would give me the text of the function, b) which I can then use to assign as variable. Why is this not advisable though?

Comment: @gyaan.anveyshak: I have added to my answer, I hope that gives a bit of an intuition - a lot (aside from misusing the interpreter frameinfo, which is just not intended for such uses as in this example) comes down to common pitfalls in achieving maintainable and (hopefully) fault-tolerant code at scale. Here is a discussion on [whether or not global variables are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that takes an extra argument.

```
def func(df, name=None, prop=True):
    fd = df.C1.value_counts(normalize=prop).reset_index()
    fd.columns = ['feature','proportion']
    if name!=None:
        globals()[name+'_fd'] = fd
    return fd

import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['A','A','B','D']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['C','C','B','D']})

func(df2, 'df2')
#   feature  proportion 
# 0       C        0.50 
# 1       B        0.25 
# 2       D        0.25

df2_fd
#   feature  proportion 
# 0       C        0.50 
# 1       B        0.25 
# 2       D        0.25

func(df1)  # will not save separately
#   feature  proportion
# 0       A        0.50
# 1       B        0.25
# 2       D        0.25

df1_fd
# NameError: name 'df1_fd' is not defined
```