# Name SQL table the same as df name in python to_sql() function

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following function that writes to SSMS, successfully, when I go in and change the `table_name` variable. But, I would like the name of whatever the df is being passed into the function to become the table name. E.g. if I am passing the df `my_test_table` into the function, I want the following SQL table to be named the same thing.

```
import urllib
import sqlalchemy

def write_to_sql(df):
    
    params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'DRIVER={};SERVER={};DATABASE={};Trusted_connection=yes;')

    conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)

    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str)

    table_name = #make this the same thing as the df name

    df.to_sql(name=table_name, con=engine, schema='yep', if_exists='replace', index=True, index_label=None, chunksize=10, dtype=None)   

write_to_sql(my_test_table) #want the table_name variable in the function to equal this
```

I have tried to  use something like `table_name = 'df'.format(df)`, but that didn't work, as it just forces the table_name to be df. What's the solution?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by df name?

If you mean the variable name that you are passing to the function, there's not really a great way in python to do that

Comment: I mean df  being whatever table I'm passing to the table. I was hoping there was a way to do it in python, without having to go in and change the `table_name` every time I write a table

Comment: This is more or less just trying to get the name of the variable passed to a function as a string within that function.

It's really not good practice but there's a few very hacky examples here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749796/how-to-get-the-original-variable-name-of-variable-passed-to-a-function