# How to write an if statement for a function argument that is a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, function, geopandas

I've written a function that does some calculations to dataframes that are passed in.

However, due to some formatting issues, one of the dataframes that is passed in needs additional work. I'd like to write an if statement within the function that determines if that specific dataframe is passed in, it will do some formatting work. The issue is the variable is a dataframe type, so I can't figure out how to just use the name to develop the if statement.

I have tried a few things, including trying to add a string to a variable name with `,` `+` or `&`. I've tried to convert the df to a string with `df.to_string()`. And I've tried a few variations on these function outlines:

```
a_df
b_df

def calc_mean_max(df):
    df_string = "a"
    if df_string in df:
        #do formatting
    else:
        #do regular calculations


def calc_mean_max(df):
    if df == "a_df":
        #do formatting
    else:
        #do regular calculations
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything on this problem, I feel like it should be a pretty straightforward solution but maybe I'm wrong. Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to look for? Is `a` a column name, a value in a column?

Comment: Do you want to know which dataframe is `df` in the function? `a_df` or `b_df`?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the name of the df. If a_df is passed in, do this, but if b_df is passed in, do this other thing. Does that make sense? @Corralien that's basically it.

Comment: No it's not really possible without [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749857/15239951)

Comment: Or you could preprocess your dataframe for columns with issues to skip this step you are dealing with. Look into [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comment, it's not possible to get the dataframe name inside your function but there is an elegant solution. You can use [`attrs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.attrs.html) dict of a dataframe (note the warning).

```
def calc_mean_max(df):
    if df.attrs['name'] == "a_df":
        #do formatting
    else:
        #do regular calculations


a_df = pd.DataFrame(...)
a_df.attrs['name'] = 'a_df'

b_df = pd.DataFrame(...)
b_df.attrs['name'] = 'b_df'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help...that's an interesting method. What is 'name' here? Looking at the documentation I'm not sure I understand that part.

Comment: `attrs` is a dict. You can store what you want. I just created an entry `name` with an arbitrary name.

Comment: Very cool - I'll be sure to note the warning, but this works for now. Thank you!!